# How to use Explicit Wait in Selenium Version 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to use Explicit Wait in Selenium Version 3.4.0 and i am getting an error on Until Method . I have Updated My guava libraries to 21 .

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='bookingType']")));
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your question acordingly

Comment: Error is :- The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)